# App::make controller method in a view section causes 502 error in nginx

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Here's my master.blade.php (url: admin):

```
@section('admin_body')
  {{ App::make('PageController')->index() }}
@show
```

Here's my index.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')
    @section('admin_body')
        <p>Hello!</p>
    @stop
```

If i visit URL: admin - i get 502 bad gateway error. When i remove contsnts of **index.blade.php** - it does work.

Comment: Is there any good reason you are calling a controller action inside a view? Are you trying to render the `index.blade.php` view inside `master.blade.php` by returning it from `PageController->index()`?

Comment: You're right. That's exactly what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the proper way to include a view inside a layout. The [Laravel Templates Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates) exemplifies 2 ways to achieve that.

### Controller Layouts

You can use controller layouts by inheriting from `BaseController` and setting the `layout` property. In your case the controller would look something like this:

```
class PageController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'master';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('index');
    }
}
```

And place this in your `master.blade.php` where you want to output the view:

```
{{ $content }}
```

### Blade Templating

Blade templating uses it's own internal inheritance system. You were on the right track by using sections and extends but here's how to correctly use it. For your controller there's more no need to extend `BaseController` and define a layout, just return the view that `@extends` the layout). So something like this:

```
class PageController {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }
}
```

Your view file `index.blade.php` would need to `@extends` a layout file (what you did was ok except you don't need the second `@stop` directive because `@extends` doesn't a closing `@stop`):

```
@extends('master')
@section('admin_body')
    <p>Hello!</p>
@stop
```

Your layout file `master.blade.php` would need to have the `@yield` directive where you want to include the view section:

```
@yield('admin_body')
```

---

#### Using `@include`

As a side note you can also use `@include('view_name')` to include a view inside another view, but for setting up layouts using any of the two aformentioned methods is best.